# Question about work done in $P$-$V$ diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, work, volume

[image]

$$A_1 = 0.5 (0.2) (1.5 \times 10^5) = 0.15 \times 10^ 5 \text{Pa m}^3$$

$$A_2 = 0.2 (1.0 \times 10^5) = 0.2 \times 10^5 \text{Pa m}^3$$

$$\frac{A_\text{total}}{\text{Work}} = 0.35 \times 10^5 ~\text{Joules}$$

So I think the answer should be $-0.35$, but this is not the correct answer.  I'm sure I'm missing something, but can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of the work is correct if the $-0.35\times 10^5$ J is the work W done by the surroundings on the gas.  But you are not done yet.  The first law tells us that $$Q+W=\Delta U$$ where Q is the *thermal energy transferred to the gas* from the surroundings and $\Delta U$ is the change in internal energy of the gas.  So, before you can determine the value of Q, you also need to calculate the change in internal energy of the gas.  For a mono-atomic gas, this is given by:
$$\Delta U=n\left(\frac{3}{2}R\right)(T_B-T_A)$$You can calculate the temperatures at states A and B by applying the ideal gas law.  Then you just calculate:  $$Q=\Delta U-W$$

Answer (score 0):

Fo the monoathomic gas you have to take de thermal energy transferred as $\frac{3}{2}nR\Delta T$. You can calculate the temperature in B and A and put into the formula. Calculating the work does not help as far as you don't know the amount of heat exchange between A and B...